# NA particle meaning?

Tags: na-adjectives

What does the NA mean in this sentence?

> Sonna baka NA koto...
>
> そんなバカ**な**ことは、普通に言わないよ
>
> Normally, (you) don't say such a stupid thing

Comment: It indicates that the previous word is an adjective.

Comment: D'oh! I just read baka was a noun and didn't really think about it being an adjective too. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For the etymology of both : [Are な and だ both copula verbs?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/are-%E3%81%AA-and-%E3%81%A0-both-copula-verbs)

In modern japanese, な is the modifying form of the copula and だ is its conclusive form.

So yeah, as Ringil said, it just means that バカ modifies こと : "a stupid thing".